# Go app hangs when testing a function that contains a lock

Tags: unit-testing, go

This is a function I wrote that adds a request to a request queue:

```
func (self *RequestQueue) addRequest(request *Request) {

    self.requestLock.Lock()
    self.queue[request.NormalizedUrl()] = request.ResponseChannel
    self.requestLock.Unlock()
}
```

and this is one of its tests:

```
func TestAddRequest(t *testing.T) {

    before := len(rq.queue)

    r := SampleRequests(1)[0]
    rq.addRequest(&r)

    if (len(rq.queue) - 1) != before {
        t.Errorf("Failed to add request to queue")
    }
}
```

When I run this test, the application hangs. If I comment out this test, everything works fine.
I think the problem is the locking inside the function. Is there something that I'm doing wrong?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: One possibility: could happen if any previous test `panic`s or returns error (or success) while holding `requestLock`. The standard thing to do is `defer self.requestLock.Unlock()` right after each `Lock()` so stuff gets cleaned up for you.

Comment: First of all as @twotwotwo mentioned, unlock it with `defer`. Second, you are accessing rq.queue in your test without locking, but if nothing else is running it could be fine. third, you don't show enough of the rest of the code to help you debug this.

Comment: I found the issue in another part of the code which, I'm sorry, I didn't provide but thanks a lot for that Defer tip. I hadn't thought of that :)

Comment: @W.K.S Could you please answer your own question and accept it, then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was an infinite loop in the SampleRequests() function:

```
func SampleRequests(num int) []Request {

    requests := make([]Request, num, num+10)
    for i := 0; i < len(requests); i++ {
        r := NewRequest("GET", "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather", nil)
        r.Params.Set("lat", "35")
        r.Params.Add("lon", "139")
        r.Params.Add("units", "metric")

        requests = append(requests, r)
    }

    return requests
}
```

I was checking if `i` was less than the length of the array in the continuation condition of the for loop. With each iteration, an item was added to the array, the length increased and the for loop continued executing.